# nodejs timestamp : compare the time and display the record sorting ascending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

hi i'm trying to display the record with condition : sorting ascending order comparing the Time-stamp.

in frontend i'm using the angularjs: **4 user** will be ready to press the **button** (while pressing the button i get the **team-name and time**)
in **nodejs** i get the **data** and I want to **compare** the **team** with **time** and try to display the **who pressed button first**

guide me plz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
var data = []

data.push({team: 1, time: 2.5})
data.push({team: 2, time: 0.05})
data.push({team: 1, time: 1.6})
data.push({team: 2, time: 8})

function goSort(data, type)
{
    if (type != "ASC" && type != "DESC")
        return;

    data.sort(function(a, b) {

        if (type == "ASC")
            return a.time - b.time;
        else
            return b.time - a.time;
    });

  return data;
}
```

Then use goSort function like this to sort by ASC :

```
goSort(data, "ASC");
console.log(data);
```

Result will print :

```
[ { team: 2, time: 0.05 },
  { team: 1, time: 1.6 },
  { team: 1, time: 2.5 },
  { team: 2, time: 8 } ]
```

or use goSort like this to sort by DESC :

```
goSort(data, "DESC");
console.log(data);
```

Result will print :

```
[ { team: 2, time: 8 },
  { team: 1, time: 2.5 },
  { team: 1, time: 1.6 },
  { team: 2, time: 0.05 } ]
```

After that you can exploit your data as you want.